# Sum of Poissons is Poisson with adding parameters

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, poisson-distribution

I am studying probability and statistics recently, in section multidimensional random variable and its distribution, I encountered a problem:

> Let $\pi(\lambda)$ denote the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Poisson random variables, $X\sim \pi(\lambda_1), Y\sim \pi(\lambda_2)$. Prove that $X+Y\sim \pi(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$.

Comment: You can easily do this by using convolutions or moment generating functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Typically such things are done by conditioning. Assume $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $X \sim \pi(a), Y \sim \pi(b)$ as you suggest. Also let $Z = X+Y$ and note that
$$
\begin{split}
F_Z(z)
 &= \mathbb{P}[X+Y \le z] \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X+Y \le z|Y=k] f_Y(k) \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X \le  z-k] f_Y(k) \\
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_X(z-k) f_Y(k),
\end{split}
$$
which is called a *convolution* of $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Can you finish?

---

Another approach is to use mgf:
$$
M_Z(t)
 = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tZ}\right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}e^{tY}\right]
 = M_X(t)M_Y(t),
$$
since $X,Y$ are independent. Can you finish this too?